# If the extended Riemann integral of f doesn't exist, then its possible to make a rearrengement

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Set f as a continous function in $\Omega$, where f has positive and negative values. Proof that if the extended integral of f doesn't exist, then for each $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, it is possible to make a sequence of close bounded sets such as $U_n^\alpha\subset\Omega$ and $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n^\alpha$ generates $\Omega$, so that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{U_n^\alpha}f=\alpha$$

I have tried that, as f is not integrable in an extended way, then $\exists\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of open sets so that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n^\alpha=\Omega$ and $U_n\subset U_{n+1}$ that makes $\{\int_{U_n}|f|\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ diverge. Then, as f gets negative and positive values, we can make $f_+\;,\;f_-$. As $|f|=f_++f_-$, then one of this functions has to diverge. Lets define $C_k:=U_n-(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}U_i)$.

Look that:
$$\int_{U_n}f_+=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{C_i}f_+$$
That's all I got, I don't know how to prove that this series is conditionally convergent, so that we can make the rearrengement.

Comment: The phrase "positive and negative" values does not accomplish what you think it does.  E.g., the function $f(x)=x-1$ on $[0,\infty)$ has "positive and negative" values and $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx =\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here is a sketch of your ideas in a simple setting.  Please explain if this is what you intended (more or less).*

Suppose $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous.

Define the open sets
$G_1=\{x\in [0,\infty): f(x)>0\}$,  $G_2=\{x\in [0,\infty): f(x)<0\}$ and the closed set
$E =  \{x\in [0,\infty): f(x)=0\}$.

Since  $G_1$ is open,  we can write it as a union of its component intervals $\{(a_i,b_i)\}$.  Similarly $G_2$ is open and we can write it as a union of its component intervals $\{(c_j,d_j)\}$.  The set  $E$ is closed and $\int_E f(x)\,dx=0.$

We will have to **assume**${}^1$ that all component intervals of $G_1$ and $G_2$ are bounded.

We will have to **assume**${}^2$  that
$$\int_{G_1} f(x)\,dx = \infty \text{ and  } \int_{G_2} f(x)\,dx =- \infty .$$

That will guarantee that there are infinitely many component intervals for each of the sets and that
$$0 < \alpha_i =\int_{(a_i,b_i)} f(x)\,dx < \infty$$
and
$$0 > \beta_j =\int_{(c_j,d_j)} f(x)\,dx > - \infty$$
but that  $$\sum_i \alpha_i =\infty \text{ and  }\sum_j \beta_j =-\infty.$$

This is still not enough for your purposes so **assume**${}^3$  also that $\alpha_i\to 0$ and $\beta_j\to 0$.

Finally **with all of these assumptions**${}^{1,2,3}$  you appear to be in the situation that (I think) you desire.  Namely take any real number $r$ and rearrange the sums of the numbers $\alpha_i$ and the $\beta_j$ into a series that sums to $r$.

This appears to show that
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx= \int_E f(x)\,dx + \int_{G_1 \cup G_2}f(x)\,dx    = r$$
if we are allowed to rearrange the order of taking the components in the two open sets.

**Final question?  Why?**